# Boost UDP Server

Tags: udp, c++17, boost-asio

I am trying to convert a Boost UDP server from using raw pointers to using `std::vector` which I believe is possible from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html

However my vector is always filled with 0 values.

```
void start_receive()
    {
        std::vector<unsigned char> recv_buffer_(64);
        socket_.async_receive_from(
                boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
                boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        std::cout << "Receive length is :" << recv_buffer_.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "recv_buffer_ = \n";
        for (unsigned char n : recv_buffer_)
           std::cout << n << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';

    }
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong ? `socket_` is a `udp::socket socket_;` and the above code works with a `unsigned char *`

Comment: Print content of vector inside `handle_receive` method. This handler (created by `bind`) will be called when async operation is completion - then you can print bytes stored in vector. Or use synchronous method to read data.

Comment: @rafix07 a silly mistake, many thanks !

Comment: my code now works with `boost::array` but not `std::vector` is there something I am missing in the call to `boost::asio::buffer` ? I should be able to simply pass the vector right ?

Comment: If you use async approach, your `vector` must be stored as member variable. In case of `array` you need to pass `type` of data + `size`, then buffer works, because it knows how many bytes must be read. Maybe your `vector` is empty as data member, try to call `resize(64)` on vector before `async_receive_from`. Or in initilizer list of your class `recv_buffer_(64)` - this calls vector ctor taking size.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks I had used `reserve` instead of `resize`. Works like a charm ;-)